# SLF4J not found on the classpath while connecting Mongodb with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, slf4j

I'm facing issue while setting up connection of Java(17.0.1) with MongoDb(5.0.3) through Eclipse.
can anyone please help to resolve this issue.

```
package DemoMongo.DemoMongo;
    
    import com.mongodb.*; import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients; import
    com.mongodb.client.MongoClient; import
    com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection; import
    com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase; import
    com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
    
    import com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions; import
    com.mongodb.client.result.*; import org.bson.Document; import
    org.bson.types.ObjectId;
    
    import java.util.List; import java.util.Arrays; import
    java.util.ArrayList;
    
    import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*; import static
    com.mongodb.client.model.Updates.*;
    
    public class DemoMongoDatabase {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {        // TODO Auto-generated
    method stub
                    // Step-1 Connection
                    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://hostOne:27017,hostTwo:27018");
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("my_database");
            MongoCollection<Document> toys = database.getCollection("toys");
            //Create a new document         Document doc = new
    Document().append("username","****").append("pwd","****");
            toys.insertOne(doc);        mongoClient.close();    }
    
    }
```

Nov 13, 2021 5:12:27 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.Loggers shouldUseSLF4J
WARNING: SLF4J not found on the classpath.  Logging is disabled for the 'org.mongodb.driver' component
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=hosttwo:27018, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: hosttwo}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: hosttwo}}, {address=hostone:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: hostone}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: hostone}}]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:177)
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AbstractMultiServerCluster.getDescription(AbstractMultiServerCluster.java:54)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:147)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:98)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:278)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:202)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1008)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:469)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:452)
at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:446)
at DemoMongo.DemoMongo.DemoMongoDatabase.main(DemoMongoDatabase.java:34)

Answer (score 0):

Add SL4J to classpath by adding it as a dependency to build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.36'
}
```

Go ahead and initialize by adding the following lines before making connection to MongoDB

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DemoMongoDatabase.class);
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```